# Rails.cache dropped after each rake task run

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm stuck of easy question:
Let's my rake task is:

```
namespace :common do
  desc 'check rails cache'
  task easy_task: :environment do
    l = -> (test_param) do
      puts "cache value isn't found, reload..."
      'this is result'
    end
    result = Rails.cache.fetch('test_task', expires_in: 1.hour) do
      l.call(1)
    end
  end
end
```

My expectations - output phrase "cache value isn't found, reload..." will output only first run of `rake common:easy_task`, but is's outputted in each run.

Also, i'm try:

```
rake common:easy_task
rails common:easy_task
bundle exec spring rake common:easy_task
bundle exec spring rails common:easy_task
```

nor of these help.

Rails cache isn't working inside rake task, but working in console and in App. Why?

Comment: Can't reproduce. Works for me. Output the first time, serving from cache the second time.

Comment: So, i guess, my Rails app config is wrong. I'm will try guess that mistake...

Comment: not so, i'm create new rails 5 app and run - each run produce output "cache isn't found"

Comment: That may be, but does it work in console/app in the same code?

Comment: yes, Rails.cache work as expected in app and in rails console

Comment: In the same new app? I don't think so. Post that app to github or something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If things are working in the console but not in a rake task, you're probably using the [ActiveSupport::Cache::MemoryStore](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Cache/MemoryStore.html) (which is the default in **config/environments/development.rb** if you have the temp file to enable caching, otherwise it uses the [ActiveSupport::Cache::NullStore](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Cache/NullStore.html), which wouldn't work anywhere, for obvious reasons), which stores things in process memory:

> A cache store implementation which stores everything into memory in the same process.

```
Rails.configuration.cache_store # => :memory_store
l = -> (test_param) do
  puts "cache value isn't found, reload..."
  'this is result'
end
Rails.cache.fetch('test_task', expires_in: 1.hour) do
  l.call(1)
end
# cache value isn't found, reload...
# => "this is result"
Rails.cache.fetch('test_task', expires_in: 1.hour) do
  l.call(1)
end
# => "this is result"
```

But won't work as well in the rake task, which uses a separate process each time

```
$ rake common:easy_task
# [:memory_store, "pid = 26230"]
# cache value isn't found, reload...
$ rake common:easy_task
# [:memory_store, "pid = 26253"]
# cache value isn't found, reload...
```

Even with spring, the process is a different one each run

```
$ bin/rake common:easy_task
# Running via Spring preloader in process 26283
# [:memory_store, "pid = 26283"]
# cache value isn't found, reload...
$ bin/rake common:easy_task
# Running via Spring preloader in process 26297
# [:memory_store, "pid = 26297"]
# cache value isn't found, reload...
```

To fix this we need to use a different memory store (I'll use [ActiveSupport::Cache::FileStore](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Cache/FileStore.html) for this example, but use whichever other one you like)

```
config.cache_store = :file_store, Rails.root.join('tmp/cache_store')
```

and then the rake task works as expected:

```
$ bin/rake common:easy_task
# Running via Spring preloader in process 26400
# [:file_store, #<Pathname:.../tmp/cache_store>, "pid = 26400"]
# cache value isn't found, reload...
$ bin/rake common:easy_task
# Running via Spring preloader in process 26414
# [:file_store, #<Pathname:.../tmp/cache_store>, "pid = 26414"]
$ bin/rails c
# Running via Spring preloader in process 26430
result = Rails.cache.fetch('test_task', expires_in: 1.hour) do
  l.call(1)
end
# => "this is result"
```

Comment: Thank you for a perfect answer and it working! So, i'l be use the :file_store instead :memory_story.

Comment: In a addition to very nice explanation there is a blog post that explains all different kind of caches - https://blog.appsignal.com/2018/04/17/rails-built-in-cache-stores.html and also states that other cache stores could be used - memcached or redis cache store. Good answer.